# If a curve has two different parametrizations, say $\gamma$ and $\beta$, then $\int_{\gamma}f(z) dz=\int_{\beta}f(z)dz?$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, definite-integrals, curves

If a curve has two different parametrizations, say $\gamma$ and $\beta$, then

$$\int_{\gamma}f(z) dz=\int_{\beta}f(z)dz?$$

I think the proposition is true. My idea is showing that the hypotesis implies that $\gamma$ is a reparametrization of $\beta$ and I already know that, in this case, we have the equality.

Please, tell me if my analysis is true. Or could I find A counterexample?

Here, $\int_{\gamma}f(z) dz=\int_{a}^{b} f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t) dt$ and $a\le t\le a$.

Comment: Sure, change of variable $\gamma(t) = \beta(\tau), \gamma'(t)dt = \beta'(\tau)d\tau$

Comment: @reuns       Could you be more specific, please? I mean, why is a variable change enough?

Comment: That's what means "parametrization of the same curve" that the change of variable $\gamma(t) = \beta(\tau)$ is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that 
 $\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz=-\int_{\gamma^-}f(z)dz$ where $\gamma^-(t):=\gamma(a+b-t)$ and $\gamma^-$ and $\gamma$ parameterize the same curve, so this is not generally true.

Comment: Are you kidding ? Obviously the direction is taken in account when we say the same curve